# getting infinite loop?

Tags: java, android, loops, serial-port, infinite-loop

I am connecting to a terminal emulator using a library in android, this connects to a serial device (a switch) and shows me sent/received data. I send data over serial using another library. I send data over the connection via a text box below the terminal or by typing in the terminal itself and hitting enter on the keyboard in both cases. I can also send commands by pressing buttons.

In my activity I have a method called `sendOverSerial` which just calls a library method to send data over usb to the device connected over serial.

```
public static void sendOverSerial(byte[] data) {

        if(mSelectedAdapter !=null && data !=null){
        mSelectedAdapter.sendData(data);

      }}
```

This activity opens an instance of a class, this class is used to write data to the terminal screen. Generally when I want to send data over serial, via the `editText` and `buttons` i call the `sendOverSerial` method in the activity. But when I am writing characters into the terminal itself they are picked up in this new instances `write` method. So I have to call the `sendOverSerial` method from that instance. My problem is that if I call it to write "TEST" below then TEST gets written to the terminal in an infinite loop, it just keeps writing it. Any idea why?  If I send it further down like I have commented it just sends once as expected.

```
 public void write(byte[] bytes, int offset, int count) {

            int numCRs = 0;
            for (int i = offset; i < offset + count; ++i) {
                if (bytes[i] == '\r') {
                    ++numCRs;
                }
            }

            if (numCRs == 0) {
                // No CRs -- just send data as-is

                //infinite loop if I send from here
                GraphicsTerminalActivity.sendOverSerial("TEST".getBytes());

                super.write(bytes, offset, count);

                if (isRunning()) {
                   doLocalEcho(bytes);
                }
                return;
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "CRs=== " + numCRs);
            // Convert CRs into CRLFs
            byte[] translated = new byte[count + numCRs];
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = offset; i < offset + count; ++i) {
                if (bytes[i] == '\r') {
                    translated[j++] = '\r';
                    translated[j++] = '\n';
                } else {
                    translated[j++] = bytes[i];
                }
            }
           //fine if I send from here, sends once
            GraphicsTerminalActivity.sendOverSerial("SECOND TEST".getBytes());
           super.write(translated, 0, translated.length);

            // If server echo is off, echo the entered characters locally
            if (isRunning()) {
                doLocalEcho(translated);
            }                            
        }
```

Super.write from the library:

```
 public void write(byte[] data, int offset, int count) {
        try {
            mWriteQueue.write(data, offset, count);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        notifyNewOutput();
    }
```

which then calls write in another class in the library, the bytequeue class

```
public void write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length)
    throws InterruptedException {
        if (length + offset > buffer.length) {
            throw
                new IllegalArgumentException("length + offset > buffer.length");
        }
        if (length < 0) {
            throw
            new IllegalArgumentException("length < 0");

        }
        if (length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        synchronized(this) {
            int bufferLength = mBuffer.length;
            boolean wasEmpty = mStoredBytes == 0;
            while (length > 0) {
                while(bufferLength == mStoredBytes) {
                    wait();
                }
                int tail = mHead + mStoredBytes;
                int oneRun;
                if (tail >= bufferLength) {
                    tail = tail - bufferLength;
                    oneRun = mHead - tail;
                } else {
                    oneRun = bufferLength - tail;
                }
                int bytesToCopy = Math.min(oneRun, length);
                System.arraycopy(buffer, offset, mBuffer, tail, bytesToCopy);
                offset += bytesToCopy;
                mStoredBytes += bytesToCopy;
                length -= bytesToCopy;
            }
            if (wasEmpty) {
                notify();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's no such thing as an "infinite loop".  Sooner or later the battery will run down, some resource will be exhausted, or some component will fail.  Or you'll just get tired of waiting.

Comment: Yes there is, it is the name of a certain type of loop. And even if it wasn't that isn't exactly a constructive comment. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop

Comment: can you post or summarize the code that calls write? Are you sure that it will display "TEST" an infinite amount of times for a single call to write?

Comment: Can we see the write code for the super.write call?

Comment: I've added the super write now, which calls another write in a  different class. I'm not sure what code calls write from the terminal, it just gets called when I press enter, it must be in the library somewhere. It seems infinite yes, it's printed thousands of times in half an hour, about 20 times a second at a guess.

Comment: put a log message at the top of each method call listed here and check the logcat output. My first impression is that there is a loop which is causing write to be called more than once. If you can confirm that you can add more log calls and trace it back to where write is being called more than once.

Comment: Run it under a debugger and just pause it. Then if you don't see the problem, step it until you do.

Comment: set a breakpoint in the write method and set the "hit count" for the breakpoint to something like 10. Then, when you hit that breakpoint have a look at the stack and it should be pretty obvious where your loop is occurring.

Comment: I can see that write is being called over and over, i will try and do teh debug now, my tablet is not connected to the pc and the debug statement did not work, so ill have to try and figure that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method was getting called automatically when data was being sent, this method also had a call to write in it, et viola, infinite loop.